# Is it possible to use a lib included in a framework in a snap in Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'm trying to use [ROS](http://www.ros.org/) on Ubuntu Core. I have followed [this example](http://www.piware.de/2015/01/snappy-package-for-robot-operating-system-tutorial/) to understand how to do it, but I want to follow a slightly different approach.

My aim is to create a framework for the main feature of ROS and independent snap for a node or group of nodes.

The point is: Can I use lib included inside the ros framework (i.e. libroscpp.so) in a snap? If so, how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We're going to add this ability, but the library will only be exposed to YOUR snaps, not snaps from anybody else. The idea is to enable you to get code and file sharing across a set of snaps without creating the sort of brittle version dependencies that plague the traditional OS.

This way, you can update the library or the app at any time, and since you control both, you can make sure you don't break yourself in doing so.